# Calculate number of Tuesdays (for example) between two dates in Apple Numbers

Tags: mac, numbers

I am attempting to calculate the quantity of a given weekday (say, how many Tuesdays, or Thursdays, etc.) between two dates. I'm running afoul of what seem to be Numbers' limitations as compared to Excel, though I can't testify that it's not just me missing a function.

I have no problem calculating the number of days:

`DATEDIF(TODAY(),Due Date Storage,"D")` with `Due Date Storage` being a date field and the formula returning the number of days.

Dividing that by 7 will provide the number of weeks, which gets me closer though still imprecise.

But I can't figure how to automatically calculate the number of Day X (some payments are made on Tuesdays, some on Thursdays, etc., so, essentially how many payments remain between now and a given due date.)

Any ideas? Can't seem to find much. 
Why Numbers? Management's request.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if payments sometimes fall on a Tuesday and sometimes on a Thursday, how do you expect to automatically calculate this out? Or are you just going to use two formulas, one for how many Tuesdays fall within your data range, and one for how many Thursdays do? Also, you mention dividing by 7, but without providing any real context to that. Would it always be '7' or could it just be any value depending on the actual date at `Due Date Storage`? (I do understand the "dividing that by 7" was a workaround to try to get what you wanted).

Comment: Two formulas. One for Tue. One for Thu. Division by 7 simply provides number of weeks to Due Date in pure days from `TODAY()`, not work weeks or calendar weeks.